# Change all uppercase letters in a named style to initial case (Indesign Grep)

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

This is my first post here. I have Peter's (forgot his last name) excellent change  case-script so I can do the replacement with no problem, but the find is baffling me.

I have a glossary where the term has been written in a character style so I can easily select all the words in that character style. It's all caps and I want to change those words to initial caps.

For example:

*ALIASING* changed to *Aliasing*.

*BALANCED INTERFACE* changed to *Balanced Interface*.

If I can somehow do a find from the second letter of each word, then hopefully I can use Peter's script to change those to lower case. Any help would be tremendous, thanks!

Comment: It may help if you posted the script.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/grep_change_case.html) the script you are speaking of? Also, it would help further if you could describe what you have already tried as well as post screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, that's the script. If you all can help me grep the upper case letters I want to convert to lower case I hope to be able to use the script to convert them to lower case. Here's a screenshot [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7a7rd907qfrahdd/AABQ2y4rlLcUKPV3oAIwSLmta). I would like to select all the blue test except for the initial character and turn it into lower case. The blue text is in a character style and it is easy for me to preselect that. I've tried a bunch of grep syntax but I'm far away from getting close.

Comment: I found it! Use negative look behind to eliminate the first letter of a word. (?<!\<).    then use the script to change to lower case. Fast...  damn!